# How do I tell the animation when to stop moving the div? Using an If statement?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate, positioning, timeline

So I am creating a timeline using positioning in Jquery, and I can easily get the it to move up and down the problem is the timeline only should go from 1943 to 2020. I have gotten the timeline to move up and down easy enough but It will go past the dates and nothing will be visible. I need to make the click function stop if it gets to the end of the timeline.

HTML:

```
<aside class="timeContainer">

    <div class="timeControlUp">
        <div id="yearUp"></div>
        <div id="decadeUp"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeHolder">
        <div class="timeView">
            <div class="longTimeline">

<!-- Year Markers -->            
                <div class="yearMarker">1943</div><div class="yearMarker">1944</div><div class="yearMarker">1945</div><div class="yearMarker">1946</div><div class="yearMarker">1947</div><div class="yearMarker">1948</div><div class="yearMarker">1949</div><div class="yearMarker">1950</div><div class="yearMarker">1951</div><div class="yearMarker">1952</div><div class="yearMarker">1953</div><div class="yearMarker">1954</div><div class="yearMarker">1955</div><div class="yearMarker">1956</div><div class="yearMarker">1957</div><div class="yearMarker">1958</div><div class="yearMarker">1959</div><div class="yearMarker">1960</div><div class="yearMarker">1961</div><div class="yearMarker">1962</div><div class="yearMarker">1963</div><div class="yearMarker">1964</div><div class="yearMarker">1965</div><div class="yearMarker">1966</div><div class="yearMarker">1967</div><div class="yearMarker">1967</div><div class="yearMarker">1969</div><div class="yearMarker">1970</div><div class="yearMarker">1971</div><div class="yearMarker">1972</div><div class="yearMarker">1973</div><div class="yearMarker">1974</div><div class="yearMarker">1975</div><div class="yearMarker">1976</div><div class="yearMarker">1977</div><div class="yearMarker">1978</div><div class="yearMarker">1979</div><div class="yearMarker">1980</div><div class="yearMarker">1981</div><div class="yearMarker">1982</div><div class="yearMarker">1983</div><div class="yearMarker">1984</div><div class="yearMarker">1985</div><div class="yearMarker">1986</div><div class="yearMarker">1987</div><div class="yearMarker">1988</div><div class="yearMarker">1989</div><div class="yearMarker">1990</div><div class="yearMarker">1991</div><div class="yearMarker">1992</div><div class="yearMarker">1993</div><div class="yearMarker">1994</div><div class="yearMarker">1995</div><div class="yearMarker">1996</div><div class="yearMarker">1997</div><div class="yearMarker">1998</div><div class="yearMarker">1999</div><div class="yearMarker">2000</div><div class="yearMarker">2001</div><div class="yearMarker">2002</div><div class="yearMarker">2003</div><div class="yearMarker">2004</div><div class="yearMarker">2005</div><div class="yearMarker">2006</div><div class="yearMarker">2007</div><div class="yearMarker">2008</div><div class="yearMarker">2009</div><div class="yearMarker">2010</div><div class="yearMarker">2011</div><div class="yearMarker">2012</div><div class="yearMarker">2013</div><div class="yearMarker">2014</div><div class="yearMarker">2015</div><div class="yearMarker">2016</div><div class="yearMarker">2017</div><div class="yearMarker">2018</div><div class="yearMarker">2019</div>

<!-- End Year Markers -->           

            <img src="img/dateButton.png" id="dateButton1" class="dateButton" />
            <img src="img/dateButton.png" id="dateButton2" class="dateButton" />
            <img src="img/dateButton.png" id="dateButton3" class="dateButton" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
/*---------- Start Timeline 2 ---------*/

.timeContainer { position: fixed; width: 100px; height: 90%; margin: 2% 0% 5% 0%; top: 0px; right: 30px; overflow:hidden;}

.timeControlUp { position:absolute; width: 100px; height: 50px; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-image:url(../img/timeButBG.png); z-index: 101; text-align:center;}

#yearUp { position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-image: url(../img/timeUp.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top left; cursor:pointer;}

#yearUp:hover { position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 50%; height: 50px; background-image: url(../img/timeUp.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: -100px 0px; cursor:pointer;}

#decadeUp { position: relative; top: -50px; left: 50px; width: 50%; height: 50px; background-image: url(../img/timeUp.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: -52px 0px; cursor: crosshair;}

#decadeUp:hover { position: relative; top: -50px; left: 50px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-image: url(../img/timeUp.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: -152px 0px; cursor:pointer;}


.timeHolder { position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100%; margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;}

.timeView { position:absolute; width: 100%; height: 28105px; top: -24820px; left: 0px; background-image:url(../img/longTimeBG3.png); background-repeat:repeat-y; background-position: top left; z-index: 90;}

.timeControlDown { position:absolute; width: 100%; height: 50px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; background-image:url(../img/timeButBG.png); z-index: 101;}

#yearDown { position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-image: url(../img/timeDown.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top left; cursor:pointer;}

#yearDown:hover { position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 50%; height: 50px; background-image: url(../img/timeDown.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: -100px 0px; cursor:pointer;}

#decadeDown { position: relative; top: -50px; left: 50px; width: 50%; height: 50px; background-image: url(../img/timeDown.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: -52px 0px; cursor: crosshair;}

#decadeDown:hover { position: relative; top: -50px; left: 50px; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-image: url(../img/timeDown.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position: -152px 0px; cursor:pointer;}

.yearMarker { position:relative; z-index: 91; top:0px; right: 0px; width: 95px; height: 365px; text-align:right; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color: #000; }


.dateButton { width: 40px; cursor:pointer;}
#dateButton1 { position:absolute; z-index: 102; top:25430px; left: 5px; width: 30px; height: 30px; text-align:right; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight:bold; color: #000; }
#dateButton2 { position:absolute; z-index: 102; top:24687px; left: 5px; width: 30px; height: 30px;}
#dateButton3 { position:absolute; z-index: 102; top:21212px; left: 5px; width: 30px; height: 30px;}

/*---------- End Timeline 2 ---------*/
```

And the Script itself:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#yearUp').click(function(){
    $('.timeHolder').animate({
        marginTop: '+=365px',
    }, 1000);
})
$('#yearDown').click(function(){
    $('.timeHolder').animate({
        marginTop: '-=365px',
    }, 1000);
})
$('#decadeUp').click(function(){
    $('.timeHolder').animate({
        marginTop: '+=3650px',
    }, 1000);
})
$('#decadeDown').click(function(){
    $('.timeHolder').animate({
        marginTop: '-=3650px',
    }, 1000);
})




})
```

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/eqW66/ Please use `;` to end all of your statements, and for many putting all of your style declarations on one line is hard to read. You can make this easier to understand by putting absolute links into where your images are, as well.

Comment: I am working within an intranet system

Comment: The only sane way I can think of doing this is to use a `var datePosition` within your `$.ready()` block (so it's locally scoped) and for each animate, add and substract the movements, and calculate and determine what the valid range of `datePosition` can be, and cancel the `$.animate()` if beyond that range.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm thinking... You could use [`$.scrollTo`](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) and use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to find the relevant year (as opposed to going up a certain amount), or... `$(this).prev()` on the current selected year div to `$.scrollTo()`. If there's no elements above/below the current, you can't "scroll to" what's not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it figured out, you have to figure out the initial position and subtract and add the position from your starting point so:

my total height for the div was 28105px

my starting point was 2011(the year):

the position of 2011 was 24829px

this on doc ready is set to 0

so you have to figure where3 to stop and start

here is the script:

```
// JavaScript Document 

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#yearUp').click(function(){
        var pos = $('.timeHolder').position();        
        if (pos.top + 365 <= 24820) {
            $('.timeHolder').animate({
                top: '+=365px',
            }, 1000);
        }else{
            return false
        }
    });
    $('#yearDown').click(function(){
        var pos = $('.timeHolder').position();        
        if (pos.top - 365 >= -2555) {
            $('.timeHolder').animate({
                top: '-=365px',
            }, 1000);
        }else{
            return false
        }
    });
    $('#decadeUp').click(function(){
        var pos = $('.timeHolder').position();        
        if (pos.top + 3650 <= 24820) {
            $('.timeHolder').animate({
                top: '+=3650px',
            }, 1000);
        }else{
            return false
        }
    });
    $('#decadeDown').click(function(){
        var pos = $('.timeHolder').position();        
        if (pos.top - 3650 >= -2555) {
            $('.timeHolder').animate({
                top: '-=3650px',
            }, 1000);
        }else{
            return false
        }
    });


});
```

mad thanks to @PJH for helping to guide the way, sorry I couldn't provide more images and stuff for the fiddle but being inside the intranet would not allow. Thanks for everyone else for their input

Answer (score 1):

Made a couple changes to get this to work.

First is that I changed the animate to use `top` positioning instead of `margin`.  Next I found the position of your last element (1943) and put a simple `if` in the `click` event that checked to see if the animation would go past this final position.  If so the animation won't fire.  You can apply this same mentality to your other functions. I usually don't like to work in absolute values for something like this but sometimes it works fine, especially when the list is static.

http://jsfiddle.net/eqW66/9/

```
$('#yearUp').click(function(){
    var pos = $('.timeHolder').position();
    if (pos.top + 365 <= 24820) {
        $('.timeHolder').animate({
            top: '+=365px',
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

UPDATE **

See the jsfiddle below for the rest of the 4 functions.  You had to switch to >= to the lowest value for moving down.

http://jsfiddle.net/eqW66/9/

```
$('#yearDown').click(function(){
    var pos = $('.timeHolder').position();

    if (pos.top - 365 >= -2920) {
        $('.timeHolder').animate({
            top: '-=365px',
        }, 1000);
    }
});

$('#decadeDown').click(function(){
    var pos = $('.timeHolder').position();

    if (pos.top - 3650 >= -2920) {
        $('.timeHolder').animate({
            top: '-=3650px',
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: 1943 is the (top:0px) and 2012 is the (top:28105px)

Comment: this worrks: $('#yearUp').click(function(){
        var pos = $('.timeHolder').position();     
  if (pos.top + 365 <= 28105) 
  {         
  $('.timeHolder').animate({
             top: '+=365px',
    }, 1000);     
  }
});

Comment: but the other way does not: $('#yearDown').click(function(){
        var pos = $('.timeHolder').position();     
  if (pos.top - 365 <= 28105) 
  {         
  $('.timeHolder').animate({
             top: '-=365px',
    }, 1000);     
  }
});

Comment: I think I am confusing things here

Comment: OK so the value for pos is 0 but the initial value for pos should be top: -24820px;

Comment: Alright so my question now is how do I get the pos to be the default number of 24820??

Comment: If you are coming the other way your `if` statement should be >= the value you are subtracting.  See update above in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are initializing `top` for the `.timeView` element, but animating `marginTop`. I would say just animate top. Then you can check if top is getting close to 0 and only animate that far. [Here's an updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqW66/6/).

I only changed the yearup event, but you should be able to figure out the rest. To detect if it's near the bottom, you'll have to use the current top value plus the height of the container, and compare that to the full scrollable height.

Comment: This doesn't prevent it from overrunning the base year (1943). Which is the problem the OP is asking about.

Comment: OK so it stops it at 1943(0), problem is when it gets to the 1943 marker (which is Top: 0) the buttons do not work anymore and it does not stop at the max height of (top: 28105px)